# How to track an email thread programmatically

Tags: email

I'm working on a system that handles customer inquiries and sends emails to customers related to their inquiries. When a customer replies, I need to know which inquiry (and email thread) the email belongs to. One customer may have multiple inquiries, so I cannot tell this just based on her email address.

I tried to google a bit and it seems that adding some kind of inquiry ID to the subject and the body may be a solution, but this is not 100% safe (customer can delete both).

I also see that for example AirBnb sends customer emails from a special, unique email address and my reply also goes back to that address, but I don't know if it is an inquiry specific email address or what.

As this seems to be a common problem in similar systems, I would appreciate any pointers to best practices.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this *completely* fits your needs, but there is a standard algorithm that mail clients use to group messages by "conversation" that is described by Jamie Zawinski [here](https://www.jwz.org/doc/threading.html) and, later, by the IETF Standards Organization, [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5256).

There are a number of implementations of this algorithm for various languages including my own [implementation in c#](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MailKit_MessageThreader.htm) ([source code](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/MailKit/MessageThreader.cs)). Typically you can search for it by the name "jwz threading algorithm".

Comment: That RFC is about IMAP, but the OP will need something that works on the message sending level (i.e., SMTP) and it needs to survive the customer's mail client munging the messages.

Comment: I was referring to the THREAD BY REFERENCES section which describes how to decide if messages are replies to each other.